# WPF: Get object visualized by (hierarchical) data template

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I've got a TreeView with a couple of items in it. The items are visualized by a simple hierarchical data template, like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="instanceTemplate">
  <CheckBox Checked="InstanceCheckChanged" Unchecked="InstanceCheckChanged">
    <Label>Hello World!</Label>
  </CheckBox>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

As you can see I've added an event handler, here's the code behind:

```
private void InstanceCheckChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
}
```

In this event handler, the sender of the event is obviously the check box itself, however the checkbox is actually visualizing my normal object. My question is, how do I get the object that the checkbox visualized? Preferably I would like to have a method with a signature like this:

```
public MyObject GetMyObject(UIElement sender);
```

Is this possible in WPF, or is there a clean way to store some metadata so that I know which MyObject was checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CheckBox's [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) will be the object that it's representing:

```
var myObject = ((CheckBox)sender).DataContext as MyObject;
```

Comment: Hey Matt, this was exactly the answer I was looking for, I knew it had to be simple, but I tried searching for variants of the title I used for this question, and all I got was unrelated answers. Thanks a lot! (will accepted it after the cool down is finished)